# How to set fixed height of the MultilineTextField in KivyMD

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, textfield, multiline, kivymd

1. I am trying to set a fixed height for MDTextField:

```
MDTextField:
    id: 'feedback_text'
    hint_text: 'Description of the problem'
    multiline: True
    mode: 'rectangle'
    size_hint: None, None
    height: 200
    max_height: "200dp"
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .35}
    size_hint_x: 0.8
```

But it doesn't work. I've try to `set size_hint: None, None` and `height: 200 (200dp, '200dp')` and it still doesn't work

2. How to make the text field expand downwards, not vertically in all directions from the middle. Otherwise it goes to other widgets

*Before*

[image]

*After*

[image]

**Environment**

Win: 11

Python: 3.8

Kivy: 1.1.1

KivyMD: 1.2.0dev

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for Your attention to my question. I solved my problem by making the kv-code like this:         
`MDTextField:
id: feedback_text
            hint_text: 'Description of the problem'
            multiline: True
            mode: 'rectangle'
            size_hint_x: .8
            size_hint_y: .3           
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .25}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by doing the following:

```
MDTextField:
    id: feedback_text
    hint_text: 'Description of the problem'
    multiline: True
    mode: 'rectangle'
    size_hint_x: .8
    size_hint_y: .3
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .25}
```